# HTTP Code 504 while uploading layer “”

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, docker, timeout, docker-registry

When trying to push images to private registry, the error  **HTTP Code 504 while uploading layer “”** is often occurring.There after it throws , **Error response from daemon: invalid registry endpoint https://registrydomain.com/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint https://registrydomain.com/v0/**, the registry seems to go into hang state. I have increased proxy_timeout to 900sec to see if there is a timeout while pushing large layers. On repeated pushes to the registry or after a while, it seems to work fine without any recycling or changes made to the registry instance.It is difficult to reproduce the errors as they just seem to work after a while. Is there any solution to mitigate these?

Answer (score 0):

If the registry is behind multiple layers like ELB, nginx proxy, a timeout can occur while pushing docker images. In such cases, using a load balancer as a proxy doesnt seem to be fruitful